# "tel:" function in Android WebView is not working with HTC Desire S (Android 4.0.4)

Tags: webview, android, tel

I have this link in Android WebView:

```
<a href="tel:XXXXXXX" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'event_category', 'event_action', 'event_label']);"><img src="call.png" width="65px" height="35px"></a>
```

When I click it using Samsung S2 (`Android 4.0.4`), HTC Wildfire (`Android 2.2.1`) or Sony Xperia Go (`Android 2.3.7`) the phone number comes up in the dialer like it is supposed to.

When I click it using HTC Desire S (`Android 4.0.4`) nothing happens. I have tried it with two HTC Desire S smartphones. It was working correctly when HTC Desire S had `Android 2.3.5`.

Any ideas how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this before, but I can't remember on which phone. I believe it was a Samsung. We couldn't do anything about it. It's probably because of what the phone manufacturer screwed on its build of Android. So don't worry too much. If it works in pure Android 4.0 (emuator or stock device), it isn't your fault. Blame the idiots who want to put a skin on top of Android.

Comment: I have not found a better answer :)